# Regex for capitalized backreference

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create the regex that highlights any group of two consecutive letters where the latter is the capitalized version of the former (which is lowercase).

For example, in the string

```
aSsdDsaAdfF
```

I want dD, aA and fF to match my given regex. To put it in another way, the string with highlights shouls be

aSs**dD**s**aA**d**fF**

I think I need to use backreferences, but I don't know how.

Could anybody please give me a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Please add which language/tool you are using. `(?-i)([a-z])(?!\1)(?i)\1` works if inline modifiers are supported.

Comment: And, explain *why* you need to do it with regex, it seems like the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: @SebastianProske now *that* is a nice and creative solution. You could add Unicode support with `(?-i:(\p{Ll})(?!\1))(?i:\1)`.

Comment: @MAP The number one problem on Q&A forums and websites is people asking why the question is being asked. This could only impede the path to a useful resolution. I am aware that a python script could solve this easily. I don't ask for the best way to solve the problem, I ask how to do it using *regex*. To humor you, it is because I want to find out if regex can be used to highlight backreferences after arbitrary functions (like upper) have been applied to them (to see if regex is of any use). For the future, instead of asking this question, try to imagine it is part of a homework assignment.

Comment: @SebastianProske Thank you so much for the solution. It works great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is this `(?-i:([a-z])(?=[A-Z]))(?i:\1)`
which uses entirely localized case modifiers that don't affect anything
else.

Explanation

```
 (?-i:                         # Cluster group with 'case sensitive' scoped modifier
      ( [a-z] )                     # (1), Lower-case
      (?= [A-Z] )                   # Lookahead, Upper-case
 )                             # End cluster
 (?i:                          # Cluster group with 'case insensitive' scoped modifier
      \1                            # Backreference to group 1
                                    # ( previous assertion guarantees this
                                    #   can only be the Upper-Cased version of group 1) 
 )                             # End cluster
```